# Can docker pull an image visable in podman and buildah?

Tags: docker, container, podman, buildah, minikube

If I run `buildah images`, I see an image that is fully visable and functional with `podman` and `buildah` toolchain,

```
$ buildah images
REPOSITORY                  TAG   IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
localhost/foobar-centos-7   92    688ca4049c1e   24 hours ago   4.13 GB
localhost/centos-base       7     fec48054ea4d   24 hours ago   325 MB
```

However, minikube doesn't yet work with Podman v2, and the driver is experimental with v1. I need these images to available to docker, which underscores minikube and is the only supported driver. Note, I don't want to have to push to an external registry or set up quay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also push directly to the docker daemon

```
IMG="localhost/foobar-centos-7:92"
podman push "$IMG" docker-daemon:"$IMG"
```

Comment: This isn't work for me, `Error: Error copying image to the remote destination: Error trying to reuse blob sha256:174f5685490326fc0a1c0f5570b8663732189b327007e47ff13d2ca59673db02 at destination: Error checking whether a blob sha256:174f5685490326fc0a1c0f5570b8663732189b327007e47ff13d2ca59673db02 exists in docker.io/library/docker-daemon: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
error parsing HTTP 401 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""`

Comment: Ahh, I see. You need to add the image name and tag to docker-daemon @rhatdan.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `podman save` and `docker import`. However this won't preserve the metadata, I tested it and it seems to work the same as with `oci-archive` and `docker-archive`.

```
img=localhost/foobar-centos-7:92
podman save --format oci-archive -o /tmp/image-oci.tar "$img"
docker import /tmp/image-oci.tar "$img"
```